# forbid date in jQuery Datepicker with three separate text boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, mindate

I work with form by emailmeform and I would like to forbid the selection of dates past before today.
How can I restrict the dates of datepicker like [this one](http://www.programmingforliving.com/2014/05/jquery-datepicker-with-three-separate-input-boxes.html) (three separate text boxes)?

I tried adding a script area containing ".datepicker ({minDate: 0})" in the header of my form, but the separation of fields day, month, and years complicates the operation!

```
    EMF_jQuery('.datepicker').datepicker({
            yearRange: '-120:+20',
            showOn: 'button',
            buttonImage: base_url+'images/calendar.png',
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                    var selectedDate = new Date(dateText);
                    EMF_jQuery('#'+inst.id+'year').val(selectedDate.getFullYear());
                    EMF_jQuery('#'+inst.id+'year-mm').val(((selectedDate.getMonth()+1)>9)?(selectedDate.getMonth()+1):('0'+(selectedDate.getMonth()+1)));
                    EMF_jQuery('#'+inst.id+'year-dd').val(selectedDate.getDate()>9?selectedDate.getDate():'0'+selectedDate.getDate());
                    EMF_jQuery('.'+inst.id+'yearformError').remove();
                    EMF_jQuery('.'+inst.id+'year-mmformError').remove();
                    EMF_jQuery('.'+inst.id+'year-ddformError').remove();

                    EMF_jQuery('#'+inst.id+'year'+','+'#'+inst.id+'year-mm'+','+'#'+inst.id+'year-dd').change();
            },
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
    });
```

HTML

```
    <div class="emf-div-field"><span class="emf-field-datetime-day">
                <input maxlength="2" id="element_21_year-dd" name="element_21_day" value="" class="emf-input-w20 validate[optional,custom[onlyNumber],length[2,2],lengthValue[1,31]]" type="text" size="2" temp_disabled="0" temp_validation_def="validate[optional,custom[onlyNumber],length[2,2],lengthValue[1,31]]">
                <label for="element_21_year-dd" class="emf-bottom-label">JJ</label>
            </span><span class="emf-sep">/</span><span class="emf-field-datetime-month">
                <input maxlength="2" id="element_21_year-mm" name="element_21_month" value="" class="emf-input-w20 validate[optional,custom[onlyNumber],length[2,2],lengthValue[1,12]]" type="text" size="2" temp_disabled="0" temp_validation_def="validate[optional,custom[onlyNumber],length[2,2],lengthValue[1,12]]">
                <label for="element_21_year-mm" class="emf-bottom-label">MM</label>
            </span><span class="emf-sep">/</span><span class="emf-field-datetime-year">
                <input maxlength="4" id="element_21_year" name="element_21_year" value="" class="emf-input-w40 validate[optional,custom[onlyNumber],length[4,4]]" type="text" size="4" temp_disabled="0" temp_validation_def="validate[optional,custom[onlyNumber],length[4,4]]">
                <label for="element_21_year" class="emf-bottom-label">AAAA</label>
            </span><span>
                <input type="hidden" id="element_21_" class="datepicker hasDatepicker" my_date_format="mm/dd/yy" value="02/15/2017" temp_disabled="0"><img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="//assets.emailmeform.com/images/calendar.png" alt="..." title="...">
            </span></div>
```

Do you have a solution?
Thanks in advance

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Provide some code that you have benn working on. We cannot make the code for you here; we can help you correct mistakes in your own code.

Comment: Of course, sorry !